# Object as Map Key in Typescript

Tags: typescript, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I wanted to create a Map object with an object as key and a number as value in Typescript. I defined the map object as follows:

```
myMap: Map<MyObj,number>;
myObj: MyObj;
```

and when I try to add a pair to this map object:

```
this.myMap[myObj]=1;
```

It tells me that TS2538 Type 'MyObj' cannot be used as an index type. Is this possible in Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `set` function e.g.

```
this.myMap.set(myObj, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is there also a way that I can bind this map's value's to an input? I tried `<input id="param{{myObj.id}}" name="param{{myObj.id}}" type="number" maxlength="10" [(ngModel)]="myMap[myObj]` in a table directive. This way, it couldn't differentiate keys, I guess it couldn't compare the keys and as far as I know there is no equals method to differentiate the map keys.

Comment: @oksuzlerOmer You might want to read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map and if you still have issues then open a new question.